# "Prepare for you" or "Prepare you"

Tags: grammar, american-english

What is more proper or actually correct. I was giving some "test data" to my friend. Do I say:

> I will prepare you some test data.

or

> I will prepare for you some test data.

Which one natives say?

Comment: I will prepare some test data for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would use "I will prepare some test data for you." At least for me, when you have a prepositional object ("to him", "for her", etc.) it's more common to put that part second, after you put the normal object (here, "some test data").

Answer (score 0):

The first one, mostly. The second is probably more technically correct, but it sounds pretty formal. It is the sort of thing that a teacher might say, if they are trying to model perfectly correct language.

Personally I'd also drop the "you," it is making the sentence awkward, and it is probably obvious that you are preparing the test data for them.

Answer (score 0):

Ditransitive verbs like *give*, *show*, have two patterns:

> Give the book to Jane.

or

> Give Jane the book.

Similarly:

> She showed the house to Henry.
>
> She showed Henry the house.

Many verbs allow the benefactive phrase "for (somebody)" to be used in the same two patterns:

> I baked a cake for Peter.
>
> I baked Peter a cake.

Your example is one of these:

> I will prepare some test data for you.
>
> I will prepare you some test data.

What is not natural is your other example *I will prepare for you some test data*.